# fixed length padding with trailing spaces

Tags: c, printf

How can I achieve fixed length padding with trailing spaces by using `sprintf`?

For example, how can I get `sprintf(buf, "The number is:%i", n)` to output 50 characters with trailing spaces?

Comment: Did you read `man 3 printf` (on Unix)? Put "printf" in the search engine of your choice?

Comment: Yes I did search and had no luck. The problem is that, I want fixed total length rather than partially fixed. Such as %10i formatting can only fix the number, it doesn't help anything about the total length.

Comment: So you don't want 50 trailing spaces, but you want the whole output to be 50 characters?

Comment: Yes! Thanks for your downstairs reply. Actually I had the same workaround as your post. However my initial thought is to find if there would be a solution with only formatting string.

Comment: Well, you could have added that to your question and saved me the work...

Comment: If you only want to use a format string, you can always build it: `int numLen = 1; if (n > 9) numLen = 2; /* more such ifs */ sprintf(formatString, "The number is: %%i%%c%%i", (50 - strlen("The number is: ") - numLen));` However, that makes the code much harder to read.

Answer (score 4):

My `man 3 printf` says:

> An optional decimal digit string specifying a minimum field width.  If
>            the converted value has fewer characters than the field width, it will be
>            padded with spaces on the left (or right, if the left-adjustment flag has
>            been given) to fill out the field width.

and

> `-'          A negative field width flag; the converted value is to be
>                         left adjusted on the field boundary.  Except for n conver-
>                         sions, the converted value is padded on the right with
>                         blanks, rather than on the left with blanks or zeros.  A -
>                         overrides a 0 if both are given.

and

> A field width or precision, or both, may be indicated by an asterisk '*' or
>        an asterisk followed by one or more decimal digits and a '$' instead of a
>        digit string.  In this case, an int argument supplies the field width or precision.

So I tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int num = 123;
    char* text = "The number is: ";
    printf("%s%-*iX\n", text, 50 - (int) strlen(text), num);
}
```

That gets:

```
The number is: 123                                X
```

(Where the X is just a marker to show the spaces for padding.)

Comment: Fantastic answer